# jQuery - resizable + draggable, the scrolling(left,top) is not added

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a problem with a dragging and resizable box. It works fine, drags and rezises fine, but i have a container that holds these elements and as soon as I trigger an overflow and attempt to rezise the div it fails and resets backs to container width. http://jsfiddle.net/JTTYM/26/

[image: preview]

---

***UPDATE:: Ok, maybe Im describing the problem wrong, Go to this url: http://jsfiddle.net/JTTYM/52 and scroll to find the green box, then attempt to resize it. Once resized the overflow scroll bars disappear. As said above, it's like the overflow values are not counted in a resize***

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If I drag the green box to the corner, without overflow, and then resize it like you show in the first image, it resizes correctly even when outside of the red box

Comment: Ok, maybe Im describing the problem wrong, Go to this url: http://jsfiddle.net/JTTYM/52/ and scroll to find the green box, then attempt to resize it. Once resized the overflow scroll bars disappear. As said above, it's like the overflow values are not counted in a resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This come from your `.layer { position: absolute; }`.

When you're using an absolute position, remember to always set a relative position on a parent, or you'll have many issues.

In your case, just add this CSS :

```
.layers_group {
   position: relative;   
}
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".live_resizable").resizable();
    $(".live_draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
.main {    
    position:absolute;
    right:25px;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    bottom: 25px; /*200*/
    overflow:auto;
    border:2px solid red;
}
.layers_group {
   position: relative;   
}
#stuff {
    width: 600px;
}
.layer {    
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    top: 900px; 
    left: 900px;
    cursor:move;
}

/* Jquery to add hangles i think */
.ui-resizable { position: absolute;}
.ui-resizable-handle { position: absolute;font-size: 0.1px; display: block;  }
.ui-resizable-disabled .ui-resizable-handle, .ui-resizable-autohide .ui-resizable-handle { display: none; }
.ui-resizable-n { cursor: n-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; top: -5px; left: 0; }
.ui-resizable-s { cursor: s-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; bottom: -5px; left: 0; }
.ui-resizable-e { cursor: e-resize; width: 7px; right: -5px; top: 0; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-w { cursor: w-resize; width: 7px; left: -5px; top: 0; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-se { cursor: se-resize; width: 12px; height: 12px; right: 1px; bottom: 1px; background:url(images/corner.gif); }
.ui-resizable-sw { cursor: sw-resize; width: 9px; height: 9px; left: -5px; bottom: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-nw { cursor: nw-resize; width: 9px; height: 9px; left: -5px; top: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-ne { cursor: ne-resize; width: 9px; height: 9px; right: -5px; top: -5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div id="stuff">
        <div class="layers_group aaasdasd">
            <div class="live_draggable live_resizable layer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake, thank you tho, I have been strugeling for a while thinking its jQuery's problem. Thank you once again. Enjoy +50 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must apply constrain movement. check it [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement)

EDIT:
Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JTTYM/51/

Comment: Can you take this http://jsfiddle.net/JTTYM/26/ and fix it so the inner green box when outside of the red container (overflow scroll) eg: drag and drop it to the side, but when its rezized it will not kill the overflow position. I will then give you points for your answer :)